# What are the do and don't for the imam whenever he start the khutba

Tags: halal-haram, khutbah

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I want to asked what are the things that imam should do and shouldn't do whenever he started the khutba, like, is the imam allow to make jokes and fun or telling story whenever he started the khutba

Comment: As is written this question can be answered in a book chapter please consider giving questions more focus and read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Waallaikum sallam waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

According to a narration giving by Jabir bin Abdullah (Radiya Allahu Anhu) who said: “The eyes of the Prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) used to turn red when giving Khutba, he used to raise his voice and used to become very angry; it was as if he were an army Warner”.

This means the person should to be serious about what his saying, so there's no need for the imam to make fun because khutba is all about delivery a message.

And Allah knows the best